# What utility should I use to establish an ftp connection to a z/OS mainframe and transfer files to the local machine inside an angular webapp?

Tags: angular, ftp, mainframe, zos, mvs

I want for the webapp user to specify a file on the server through a text field, then for the file to be downloaded to the local machine. Optionally, the user might also specify the login for the FTP connection, or it could be hardcoded in the application. I've tried googling but haven't had much luck.

Comment: What is an MVS1 mainframe?  z/OS?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie yeah, MVS1 mainframe is z/OS. I haven't tried anything yet. I don't know where to start.

Comment: This sort of thing comes up a lot.  [Here](https://github.com/cschneid-the-elder/rants/blob/master/advice-reading-mainframe-data.md) are some things to consider.

Comment: Have you spoken to your sysprog?  Have you tried FTPing the data manually?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and there are many things for us to assume.

Generally speaking, if the z/OS system has an FTP server running and you know the access details (host/IP address, ports/encryption used and credentials) you can just use FTP as you would with any other non-z/OS system. Often, I saw the regular FTP server that is shipped with USS is used and you can use your regular RACF credentials to log on to the system. 
This leaves you with the freedom to use any package that you feel comfortable with using in your webapp.

The only real difference to an non z/OS system would be that with regular FTP(S) you can directly access MVS files just by specifying the dataset name. If your mainframe shop only has SFTP enabled you will have to give some extra thought on accessing MVS files as they cannot be referenced by the GET command. You would need to create a procedure which first copies the datasets from MVS to USS ([as described by IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.foto100/sftpmvs.htm)).